# Rabbitmq nodes unable to restart : Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: ansible, rabbitmq

I am configuring ansible scripts for creating HA setup for rabbitmq with 3 nodes, after the whole script is executed it runs handlers to restart rabbitmq server, but it is failing to restart the nodes. Initially when i was running the script without copying the erlang cookie in the other nodes, it was running well, but when i copied erlang cookie in the other nodes, it is not restarting.

**tasks/main.yml**

```
---
- name: Install prerequisites
  apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    update_cache: yes
    state: present
  with_items:
   # - apt-transport-https
   # - ca-certificates
   # - python3-pip
   - curl
   - software-properties-common

#- name: packages - install erlang
#  apt:
#    pkg: erlang
#    update_cache: yes
#    cache_valid_time: 3600
#    state: latest

- name: "add the official rabbitmq repository's key"
  apt_key:
    url: "https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-release-signing-key.asc"
    state: present
  when: not rabbitmq_os_package

- name: Add RabbitMQ APT repository
  apt_repository:
    repo: 'deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq-erlang/debian bionic erlang-22.x'
    state: present

- name: Install RabbitMQ
  apt:
    deb: "https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/download/v3.8.3/rabbitmq-server_3.8.3-1_all.deb"

- name: enable rabbitmq plugins
  rabbitmq_plugin:
    names: rabbitmq_management,rabbitmq_tracing,rabbitmq_federation,rabbitmq_shovel,rabbitmq_shovel_management
    state: enabled
  notify:
  - rabbitmq restart

- name: Capturing Erlang Cookie On Master
  command: "cat {{ rabbitmq_erlang_cookie_file }}"
  become: true
  register: "rabbitmq_erlang_cookie"
  when: inventory_hostname == "rabbit-node1"

- name: Check if rabbitmq_conf_vm_memory_high_watermark is under the recommended range
  fail:
    msg: "The recommended vm_memory_high_watermark range is 0.4 to 0.66."
  when: rabbitmq_conf_vm_memory_high_watermark < 0.4 or rabbitmq_conf_vm_memory_high_watermark > 0.66

- name: copy the rabbitmq configuration file
  template:
    src=rabbitmq.config.j2
    dest={{ rabbitmq_config_file_path }}
    owner={{ rabbitmq_config_file_owner }}
    group={{ rabbitmq_config_file_group }}
    mode={{ rabbitmq_config_file_mode }}
    backup=yes

#- name: generate rabbitmq environment-variables file
#  template:
#    src=rabbitmq-env.conf.j2
#    dest={{ rabbitmq_env_variables_file_path }}
#    owner={{ rabbitmq_config_file_owner }}
#    group={{ rabbitmq_config_file_group }}
#    mode={{ rabbitmq_config_file_mode }}
#    backup=yes
#  when: rabbitmq_conf_env is defined

- name: alter number of system's open file if rabbitmq_system_number_open_files is set
  block:
    - name: check if value is under 500k
      fail:
        msg: "The number of open files in the system should not exceed 500K."
      when: rabbitmq_system_number_open_files > 500000

    - name: make sure service.d exists
      file:
        path: "{{ rabbitmq_service_d_path }}"
        state: directory

    - name: change limit of system's number of open file
      template:
        src: limits.conf.j2
        dest: "{{ rabbitmq_service_d_path }}/limits.conf"
        backup: true
  when: rabbitmq_system_number_open_files is defined

- name: Capturing Erlang Cookie On Master
  command: "cat {{ rabbitmq_erlang_cookie_file }}"
  become: true
  register: "rabbitmq_erlang_cookie"
  when: inventory_hostname == "rabbit-node1"

- name: Setting Erlang Cookie Of Master on Non-Master
  set_fact:
    rabbitmq_erlang_cookie: "{{ hostvars['rabbit-node1']['rabbitmq_erlang_cookie']['stdout'] }}"
  when: inventory_hostname != "rabbit-node1"

- name: Copy erlang cookie
  template:
    src: erlang.cookie.j2
    dest: "{{ rabbitmq_erlang_cookie_file }}"
    owner: rabbitmq
    group: rabbitmq
    mode: 0400
    # backing up in case the need to recover
    backup: yes
  become: true
  when: inventory_hostname != "rabbit-node1"
  notify:
  - rabbitmq restart

- name: ensure the users are removed
  rabbitmq_user:
    user={{ item }}
    state=absent
  with_items: "{{ rabbitmq_users_remove }}"

- name: ensure users exist
  rabbitmq_user:
    user: "{{ item }}"
    password: 
    vhost: /
    configure_priv: .*
    read_priv: .*
    write_priv: .*
    tags: "{{ rabbitmq_administrator_tag }}"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ rabbitmq_users }}"

- name: ensure rabbitmq server is running
  service:
    name: rabbitmq-server
    daemon_reload: true #changed systemd conf file
    state: started
```

Here is the handlers file which runs at the end of the script.

**handlers/main.yml**

```
---

- name: rabbitmq restart
  service:
    name: rabbitmq-server
    state: restarted
```

**error**

```
fatal: [rabbit-node2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to restart service rabbitmq-server: Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.\nSee \"systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service\" and \"journalctl -xe\" for details.\n"}                                                                     

fatal: [rabbit-node3]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to restart service rabbitmq-server: Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.\nSee \"systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service\" and \"journalctl -xe\" for details.\n"}
```

By checking systemctl status in nodes, it displays the following message:

```
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service.d
└─limits.conf
Active: activating (start) since Thu 2020-04-16 09:27:18 UTC; 889ms ago
Process: 929 ExecStop=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl shutdown (code=exited
status=78)
Main PID: 7865 (rabbitmq-server)
Tasks: 23 (limit: 4703)
CGroup: /system.slice/rabbitmq-server.service
├─7865 /bin/sh /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server
├─7981 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-10.7.1/bin/beam.smp -- -root /usr/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /var/lib/rabbitmq -- -pa /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.8.3/ebin -boot start_clean -noshell -no
├─7991 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-10.7.1/bin/epmd -daemon
└─7995 erl_child_setup 65535
```

By applying journalctl -xe command i got the below message:

```
rabbit-node2 rabbitmq-server[16137]: Crash dump is being written to: /var/log/rabbitmq/erl_crash.dump...done
rabbit-node2 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
rabbit-node2 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
rabbit-node2 systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
```

Comment: And what is the outcome of the checks the error message is asking you to perform? => `See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details`. Having a look at rabbitmq logs might help as well. If you find any valuable information, please edit your question and add it there.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the output of the status commands.

Comment: And what is the outcome of looking at the `Crash dump is being written to: /var/log/rabbitmq/erl_crash.dump` ? You are also allowed to dig into the problem yourself if this next step points you to another file or issue to investigate and to give all the info you have gathered at once at the end. Meanwhile it becomes obvious that this has nothing to do with ansible specifically and programming in general. Therefore, it's [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO. I suggest you try https://superuser.com

Answer (score 7):

Can Try this process:

- ps -ef | grep rabbit

If the command above showing the no. of processes < 5, then continue to next steps.

- Empty the directory /var/lib/rabbitmq/*
- sudo invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start
- ps -ef | grep rabbit

Now, run http://localhost:15672.

Note:  1) The code is tested on Localhost not on Server.
2) Enable the RabbitMQ UI with command: rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management